# Couldn't find Store with subdomain =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I have the following problem: when I go to http://lvh.me:3000 or http://www.lvh.me:3000, I get this error:

> Couldn't find Store with subdomain =
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `set_current_store'

with subdomains, it works great (so if I go to http://store.lvh.me, it works perfectly. only the root doesn't work).

Here is my code:

url_helper.rb

```
module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain].join
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_store
  include UrlHelper
  protect_from_forgery

  private
    def set_current_store
      @current_store = Store.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomains.first)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :stores

  constraints(Subdomain) do
    match '/' => "stores#show"
    resources :stores
    resources :pages, path: "strani"
  end

  root to: "stores#index"
```

subdomain.rb

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end
end
```

Comment: why do you need a `!` on the `find_by_subdomain`, I think you need to have a default `domain` that would be available when the `sub_domain` cannot be found, as in the case of the question

Comment: Thanks, removing the exclamation mark helped. Write it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the bang `!` on `find_by_subdomain` and supplied a default subdomain

e.g:

```
@current_store = Store.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomains.first) || default_subdomain
```